# how to get category path in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category

I am importing categories in magento 1.9 . but when i import categories it shows error "Path provided is not a valid one" how can i get exact path of category. URGENT [image]

[image]

Comment: Share csv screenshot that you are importing

Comment: category path is empty when i fetch categories. and i get path from database like "1/2/16" but it says not valid path

Comment: Did you know to write path in correct format ?

Comment: As far as I know, there is not import category feature in magento 1.9, are you using any external plugin?

Comment: yes i am using extension url: http://www.magentoworks.net/importexport-magento-category-extension/

Comment: did you know a way to import categories?

Answer (score 0):

The path that you are using is not invalid **"1/2/16"**

What giving you the error is the wrong ID of category. Make sure all the IDs in path are valid category IDs.

In magento 1.9, mostly category path starts with **2** Since 2 is the default category ID.

**#Edit:**

One more thing to ensure: Last ID of path should be equal to the name of the category. Like ID 16 name should be equal to the name in csv

**#Edit 2:**

You need to dubug `function getCategoryIdFromPath()` in file `app\code\local\Mageworks\Import\Helper\Category.php`

This is the function responsible for the error that you are facing.
If this function returns empty array then error will appear

Comment: i tried like "2/16" but i says not valid . is it correct syntax like"2/16/37" ?

Comment: Please check updated answer.

Comment: i tried by using small letter names for column then it says invalid header. yes ID's are correct

Comment: any thing more you know ? thanks for your answers

Comment: Did you verify name of category? it should be the category name of last ID in path

Comment: yes, i verified all id's & names , i think its syntax issue

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: how to Debug ? means what i do for de-bug ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116141/discussion-between-syze-developer-and-shoaib-munir).